# Why i am not able to load Advertisement sometimes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, admob

I have implemented AdMob to My Application from this Docunemtation: [Here](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html)

I can see the ad perfectly as I want. But some times I cant able to see the advertisements. If i refresh the activity, it will show me the Advertisement again. and ita work perfectly.

But when i am not able to see the advertisement at that time i got the message at catlog like:

```
09-27 12:58:54.451: INFO/Ads(940): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)
```

I dont know where is the Problem ?
Why I am not able to see the Add sometimes ??
Please give the way if I am wrong regarding it.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not a problem at your end but the problem at provider end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AdMob ads appear at a specified interval depending on the network traffic. If there is no congestion in the traffic, the ads appear each time you see your app else you see the message in your log saying no ad returned. However have a quick walkthrough with your code and keep testing your app after giving some gap.

With regard to refresh, in your AdMob account, go to setting, there you can specify the time when do you want the ads to refresh. There is still a possibility of the same ads appearing again and again.

Why dont you use the latest Google AdSense-SDK? Google AdSense has good ads.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the Reply. Is it Hard to implement the Google AdSense ?

Comment: The most important word in this whole description "congestion"

Comment: Not at all. Google has taken over AdMob and it has now become google-admob. Their ads are called AdSense. They follow the same procedure. just create an account with AdMob. Download the latest SDK for Android,implement those few lines of code in your XML and you are done :)

Comment: Ok Thanks Rashmi. I will try it out. But should it Display at every time ? I mean the Problem like above question arrise in this AdSence ?

Comment: Any ads that you put do not guarantee that they will display everytime. It solely depends on the network providers' congestion.Best practice, when you start the emulator, start your logcat as well. when the screen with ads appear, you will be notified if ads are appearing or not. If they dont, do not freak out, they will appear after sometime. But all this, only when you have properly included the SDK code in your xml

Answer (score 2):

I was also faced this issue but There is no any issue at our end, Admob is not appear sometime so may be it is problem at AdMob end like as server problem, netproblem...etc

Answer (score 0):

All that is needed to add AdSense ads is to press a button to enable Google AdSense in the App Settings in your app on admob.com.